# Must an inner product space have euclidean geometry?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, inner-products

My understanding of the phrase "a set has euclidean geometry" is that such a set satisfies the axioms of euclidean geometry, i.e., is a model of euclidean geometry in the sense of Model Theory. I know that finite dimensional real inner product spaces have euclidean geometry. An inner product on a vector space enables one to define geometrical constructions on the vector space, so I guess all inner product spaces (over an arbitrary field) should have *some* geometry. Must it be euclidean?

Comment: What are the axioms of Euclidean geometry?

Comment: What is an inner product space over an arbitrary (say, finite) field?

Comment: Also, the geometry (whatever that precisely means) should depend on the field. For example if you pick $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, then there need not be a point strictly "between" two given points.